# ORM: authorization via reachability

Tags: orm, authorization

We are building a webapplication which uses a database. Also we use an object relational mapper to access the database. One aspect of authorization in the webapplication is that the *user* may access an object referred to by an URL. The URL contains a unique id (for example the Primary Key) to a specific record in the database. Consider the following example.

- a *user* may belong to many *groups* and a *group* may have many *users* (many-to-many).
- a *survey* belongs to a *group* (many-to-one).
- a *survey* may have multiple *questions*. (many-to-one).

Say we have the following URL: http://app.local/question/edit/10. This means we want to edit *question* with PK 10. Now, we want to verify if the logged in *user* may access *question* with PK 10. This can be done by retrieving this *question*, then it's *survey* then it's *group* and then all its *users*. If any of the *users* is the same as the logged in *user* the logged in *user* may access the *question*.

To generalize this a bit; we want to check if a record is *reachable* from another record by the known many-to-one or many-to-many relations. So if there is a many-to-one relation (like with a *survey* and a *question* then we should check if a *user* is reachable from the *question* through the *survey* and then through the *group*. The *group* has a many-to-many relation with the *user* so we should check if any (not all) of the *users* is the same as the logged in *user*.

If a table has multiple many-to-one relations, say; we can attach a CSS *template* to a *survey* and this *template* also belongs to a *group* then we have to check if a *user* is reachable from all many-to-one relations (thus the *group* and the *template*). The same holds of course for multiple many-to-many relations.

Are there Object Relation Mappers which support this behaviour? And what is this behaviour called, maybe reachability? Does Propel (for PHP) support this behaviour? I think this reachability can be done in any of the following two ways:

- Execute a query to get each "parent", uses many queries)
- Join all necessary tables to see if a record exists (the reachable users matches the logged in user) in one query.

Furthermore this behaviour of the ORM should support nested sets, thus if a *group* contains nested set behaviour it should also try to reach a user through the *group*'s parent.

I don't think this kind of behaviour should be restricted to authorization; objects should simply be able to see if they can reach another object.

Note that I do not mean persistence by reachability: http://jpaobjects.sourceforge.net/m2-site/main/documentation/docbkx/html/user-guide/ch08s03.html.

Or... am I simply looking at this authorization wrong and is there a far better and different approach with an ORM?

Answer (score 1):

I've handled this in the past using nested resources in Ruby on Rails (which uses the Active Record ORM). Rather than http://app.local/question/10/edit, the URI would be http://app.local/survey/5/questions/10/edit

In the controller you load both the question and survey. You check authorization by comparing the survey to the authenticated user's group memberships. One way to engineer this would be to  embed this logic into the User class. For example, in the controller you have `question` and `survey` (and the relationship between the two is well understood by the ORM, i.e. `question.survey`).  You could then check access as `user.hasAccess?(question)`, which would be a relatively easy method to write. Pseudocode:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def hasAccess?(question)
    return question.group.users.include?(self)
```

Yes, this will result in several queries behind the scenes, but ORMs do the work. I do it this way because you're left with solid schema and easy to read code. Don't optimize until you actually have a performance problem.